Blazor MudTabs setting the active tab programmatically
I'm trying to set the active tab programmatically but I cant get it to work, this is the tabs definition


<MudTabs Elevation="1" Rounded="true" @ref="tabs">



and this is the C# code I'm using to set the active tab
public required MudTabs tabs;-- defined at the top of code behind

await InvokeAsync(() => tabs.ActivatePanel(5,true));
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

the active tab isn't being set here, If I use a non async version like this
tabs.ActivatePanel(5,true)
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

I get this error

System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The
current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use
InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering
rendering or component state.   Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
StackTrace:    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged() in
/_/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs:line 117    at
MudBlazor.MudTabs.d__174.MoveNext()    at
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_1(Object state)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()    at
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here ?
(I'm aware its zero based, the tab number is the correct one I want to show)

You need to provide more context on how your code is setup. There should be no issue using a non async implementation. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYGSafmKyvHXvvMD

There's a simpler way to change active tab and that is to use MudTabs.ActivePanelIndex property.
For example,
<MudTabs Elevation="0" Outlined="true" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item One" ID='"pn_one"'></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Two" ID='"pn_two"'></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Three" ID='"pn_three"'></MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>
<MudText>@($"Active Index: {activeIndex}")</MudText>

<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" OnClick="ChangeTab">Change tabs</MudButton>
@code { 
    int activeIndex = 1;

    void ChangeTab()
    {
        if(activeIndex<2){
            activeIndex++;
        }else{
            activeIndex=0;
        }
    }
}

Here, we bind it to activeIndex field using @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex", now all we need to do to change the active tab is to change that field.
Demo  MudBlazor Snippet
